# Compatibility of argument types

Tags: flutter, dart, type-safety

I wonder if my thinking is correct, or I'm making some big mistake. Let's have simple code:

```dart
class A { String a = "a"; }

class B extends A { String b = "b"; }

void goofy(Map<String, A> map) {
  A? item = map["b1"];
  print(item?.a);
}

void croc(dynamic map) {
  final A? item = (map as Map<String, A>)["b1"];
  print(item?.a);
}

void frape(dynamic map) {
  final A? item = (map["b1"]) as A;
  print(item?.a);
}


void main() {
  Map<String, B> mapInst = {"b1":B()};
  goofy(mapInst);
  croc(mapInst);
  frape(mapInst);
  
  Map<String, A> mapInst2 = {"b1":A()};
  goofy(mapInst);
  croc(mapInst);
  frape(mapInst);
}
```

All functions `goofy` , `croc` and `frape` works as expected. However I'm not so sure about signatures. Do `Map<String,A>` is compatible with `Map<String,B>` since B inherits from A? Or this is just a side effect, and in reality it matters that base type is Map and generics are not taken under consideration? Which syntax is recommended for situation when I want to pass Maps which can have A or B type in generic signature? Maybe just plain Map?

Comment: I would just use plain Map if the data types don't have to be "safe" or known

Comment: I want to have Map, which has values which inherits from some base class. But I don't know if it possible to express this in Dart :/

Comment: You can use dynamic to indicate unknown or variable type. Map<String, dynamic> although that comes with its own set of issues.

Comment: Yep, but I'm looking to something similar to java notation ```<T super X>``` or ```<T extends X>``` not just a dynamic which can eat everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do `Map<String,A>` is compatible with `Map<String,B>` since B inherits from A

Yes, if `B` did not inherit from `A`, the code would not compile.

> Which syntax is recommended for situation when I want to pass Maps which can have A or B type in generic signature?

As you said in one of your comments, you can use the extends keyword on a type argument

```
void myFunction<T extends A>(Map<String, T> map) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

If a class `Derived` derives from a class `Base`, then `Generic<Derived>` will be considered to be a subtype (a more specific type) of `Generic<Base>`.

> Do `Map<String,A>` is compatible with `Map<String,B>` since B inherits from A?

Depends on what you mean by "compatible".  `Map<String, B>` is *substitutable* for `Map<String, A>`.  That is, you may safely pass a `Map<String, B>` where a `Map<String, A>` is expected.  However, the reverse is not safe (and therefore would require an explicit cast).

> Which syntax is recommended for situation when I want to pass Maps which can have A or B type in generic signature?

I would use `Map<String, A>`.